JOIN с самим собой
Можно подробнее описать этот запрос нарастающего итога?
SELECT O1.OrderID, O1.Freight, SUM(O2.Freight) FROM Orders O1
INNER JOIN Orders O2 ON O2.OrderID <= O1.OrderId
GROUP BY O1.OrderID, O1.Freight

Я понимаю как работает INNER JOIN.
Но почему мы пишем SUM(O2.Freight), а не SUM(O1.Freight) мне не понятно.
Если сделать SUM(O1.Freight), то результат другой соответственно. Спасибо!

В запросе Freight, в картинке - Price, в запросе 3 поля возвращается - в картинке 2... Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос

почему мы пишем SUM(O2.Freight), а не SUM(O1.Freight) мне не понятно А вы замените группировку на сортировку, выведите просто поле вместо суммы, и посмотрите, что будет группироваться. На табличке в 3-4 записи. Хотя сейчас такой ерундой уже никто не мается, ибо есть оконные функции.

Объясняющий пример.

Создадим исходные данные.

CREATE TABLE Orders
SELECT 1 OrderID, 1 Freight UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3;


Ваш запрос

SELECT O1.OrderID, O1.Freight, SUM(O2.Freight) FROM Orders O1
INNER JOIN Orders O2 ON O2.OrderID <= O1.OrderId
GROUP BY O1.OrderID, O1.Freight
ORDER BY O1.OrderID, O1.Freight




OrderID
Freight
SUM(O2.Freight)




1
1
1


2
2
3


3
3
6




Как работает ваш запрос?

Выведем детально каждую связанную строку.
SELECT O1.OrderID, O1.Freight, 
       O2.OrderID, O2.Freight,
       SUM(O2.Freight) OVER (PARTITION BY O1.OrderID, O1.Freight) AS `SUM(O2.Freight)`
FROM Orders O1
INNER JOIN Orders O2 ON O2.OrderID <= O1.OrderId
ORDER BY O1.OrderID, O1.Freight




OrderID
Freight
OrderID
Freight
SUM(O2.Freight)




1
1
1
1
1


2
2
1
1
3


2
2
2
2
3


3
3
1
1
6


3
3
2
2
6


3
3
3
3
6



fiddle

Условие O2.OrderID <= O1.OrderId означает, что в O2 будут все, (видимо заказы) номер которых меньше или равен текущему из O1, то есть все предшествующие текущей строке и сама текущая строка.
Это собственно определение нарастающего итога — сумма из всех предшествующих строку плюс текущая.
